# Aligning center on flexWrap

Tags: css

I have an div`#ct` and it contains 5 child div`.content`. I want to have three on the first row and two on the second row with `flex-wrap` and centering them. The problem is that the width of each child div is longer than its actual content width by using `flex-basis`. Please run the code below for better understanding.

```css
#ct {
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   gap: 9px 30px;
   justify-content: center;
}

.content {
   flex-basis: 28%;
}

.content {
   background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="ct">
   <div class="content"><p>Content</p></div>
   <div class="content"><p>Content</p></div>
   <div class="content"><p>Content</p></div>
   <div class="content"><p>Content</p></div>
   <div class="content"><p>Content</p></div>
</div>
```

I have also tried with `grid` and it solve the width problem but I just cannot center them.

```css
#ct {
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: repeat(3, auto);
   gap: 9px 30px;
   justify-content: center;
}

.content {
   flex-basis: 28%;
}

.content {
   background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="ct">
   <div class="content"><p>Content</p></div>
   <div class="content"><p>Content</p></div>
   <div class="content"><p>Content</p></div>
   <div class="content"><p>Content</p></div>
   <div class="content"><p>Content</p></div>
</div>
```

Expected result >>> [image]

To conclude, the flex solution forces the content to be grow and the grid solutoin cannot center the items. Anyone can solve this?

Answer (score 0):

```css
#ct {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.content {
  flex: 1 0 calc(33.33% - 20px); /* Adjusted to 33.33% (1/3) minus gap */
  max-width: calc(33.33% - 20px); /* Adjusted to 33.33% (1/3) minus gap */
  margin: 5px; /* Gap between items */
  background-color: green;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Additional styling to make the content look nicer */
.content p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div id="ct">
  <div class="content"><p>Content</p></div>
  <div class="content"><p>Content</p></div>
  <div class="content"><p>Content</p></div>
  <div class="content"><p>Content</p></div>
  <div class="content"><p>Content</p></div>
</div>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Is this solution to your problem:

```css
#ct {
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   gap: 9px 0;
   justify-content: center;
   width: 400px;
}

.content {
   flex-basis: 28%;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
}

p {
   background-color: green;
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
   width: 70px;
   height: 70px;
   margin: 0;
   font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="ct">
   <div class="content"><p>Content</p></div>
   <div class="content"><p>Content</p></div>
   <div class="content"><p>Content</p></div>
   <div class="content"><p>Content</p></div>
   <div class="content"><p>Content</p></div>
</div>
```

Comment: No... I have attached a picture in the question for the expected result.

Comment: @karchung I have updated the answer, so check again please. Just be aware that we don't have a whole image of how that need to fit inside some page, so if that is it, you adjust css according to your needs.